# Upload a folder with Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, upload, asihttprequest

I'm currently using the ASIHTTPREQUEST library to upload files to a server. However, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to upload a folder instead of individual files. To upload files,  I'm using the following code:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com"]] autorelease];
[request setFile:filePath forKey:@"uploadedfile"];
[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];
```

Is there a way to upload an actual folder using this library, or is there an alternative method outside the scope of the ASI libraries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send each file independently.  That is just the nature of HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try e.g. zipping up the folder and sending the zipped file.